# Why outlook doesn't update addressList

Tags: outlook, mapi

Why outlook doesn't update address list and calendars list?

I've added an Exchange account via the standard account manager in outlook. But never the less I don't see any addressLists ("GAL", "All contacts" and so on) of my just added Exchange account. After outlook restart they are appeared in outlook...

Comment: Is this a programming question or a UI question? As for the Outlook UI - doesn't it warn you when adding a new account that you need to restart the client?

Comment: 1) It is a UI question because the Outlook behavior is the same in case when I add a new exchange account through the standard UI or when I add custom ab-provider programmatically. Outlook UI doesn't show new ab-hierarchy till I restart application. 2) Nope, as a user I don't see any warnings about restart needs in case when I add Exchange account. 3) May be outlook has some settings to make a manual or automatic refresh for address book hierarchy without Outlook restart??